# How to replace in WebStorm/PhpStorm with regex

Tags: regex, replace, phpstorm, webstorm

I want to replace

```
#{account_nbr}
```

with

```
{{account_nbr}}
```

in the find, I tried this:

```
\#\{()\w+\1\}
```

and in the replace, this:

```
{{\$1}}
```

The find seems to work but I can't get the backreference correctly.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You do not need any backreferences the way you are using them.

This is the regex you can use:

```
\#\{(\w+)\}
```

Replacement should be

```
{{$1}}
```

When you use `\$`, a literal `$` is used, not the actual back-reference.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jB9jB7/1)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/WhBQMmO.png to be clear back reference used only to store word for replace. Your regexp work fine =)

Comment: Great. Thanks for the quick answer! Does that mean that the backreference is everything inside the parenthesis?

Comment: What is inside *unescaped* parentheses is called a *capturing group* (http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). When we use `\1` in the regex itself, or `$1` in the replacement string, it is a *back-reference* (http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacebackref.html).

Comment: You can give the matched reference even a name. With `\#\{(?<value>\w+)\}` and recall the reference in the replacement with `{{\g<value>}}`

Comment: But like that, it doesn´t work in PHPStorm. Instead with this regex syntax, it should: matched case: `\#\{(?<value>\w+)\}` recall for replacement `{{${value}}}`